# lftp, let's encrypt and ca-certificates

Tags: encryption, ftp, ssl

Ubuntu 20.04

I use lftp to connect to a server (ftp.domain.xxx).

I got "Certificate verification: unable to get local issuer certificate".

Reading this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44095714/3206025
 I added

```
set ssl:ca-file "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

both in `~/.lftp/rc` and when starting lftp, to be sure to make correctly the things.

But the problem still happen.

SO I Suppose that `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` does not contain the certificate/is not enought to work.

I think that the certicate was generated true let's encrypt mechanism.

Does Ubuntu able to recognize let's encrypte certificates (outside of firefox).

How could I solve my issue ?

Comment: Ubuntu does recognize certificates from Let's Encrypt and the CA certificate should be in the file you've specified. It is more likely that the server setup is broken, for example in that it does not send the necessary chain certificates. Hard to tell for sure without knowing which server you are trying to access.

Comment: it is ftp@lautre.net

Comment: How can I "trackback" the certificates?

Comment: *"How can I "trackback" the certificates?"* - I don't understand what you mean by this.

Comment: You saiy " it does not send the necessary chain certificates". So I asked "how can I remote the chain" (sorry, English is not my native language), but you answer is ok.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not caused by a bad setup at the client but by a bad setup at the server. The server is only providing the leaf certificate and not the chain certificates which are needed to create the trust path to the local root CA - see [SSL Certificate framework 101: How does the browser actually verify the validity of a given server certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity) for more (the post is about browsers but it is the same for FTP clients).

The wrong setup can be determined with `openssl s_client`:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect lautre.net:21 -starttls ftp
...
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=lautre.net
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
...
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

As can be seen here, the server sends only the leaf certificate. A proper setup would instead look like this:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect some-other-server
...
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=some-other-server
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
 ...
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Here the expected chain certificate for `Let's Encrypt Authority X3` is provided so that the trust chain can be created against the local root CA `DST Root CA X3`.